# How to get first match with sed?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I am tired of this sed :D So I have a small file:

```
version = "1.1"
group= "com.centurion.eye"
archivesBaseName = "eye"

impmet {
    version = "4.1614"
    runDir = "eclipse"
}
```

And here is my sed command:

```
sed -n -e '/version/ s/.* = *//p' "build.gradle"
```

And I need to get ONLY version 1.1. So when I execute this command, the output is:

```
"1.3"
"4.1614"
```

But desired one is:

```
"1.3"
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: did you get a chance to check my solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pipe your commands output to `head -1` to get only the first entry.

```
sed -n -e '/version/ s/.* = *//p' "build.gradle" | head -1
```

Sample Run

```
[ /c]$ cat build.gradle
version = "1.1"
group= "com.centurion.eye"
archivesBaseName = "eye"

impmet {
    version = "4.1614"
        runDir = "eclipse"
        }
[ /c]$ sed -n -e '/version/ s/.* = *//p' build.gradle | head -1
"1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: While this is definitely the simplest approach I will say it doesn't work for my use-case at all. I have a MASSIVE file that I'm running sed against and I really need to stop processing the millisecond I get a match. This command will still wait for sed to complete before outputting the top result.

Answer (score 17):

Quit after matching the first one.

```
sed -n -e '/version/ {s/.* = *//p;q}' build.gradle
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed, you can also use `0` in the address range to apply substitution only on the first match:

```
sed -n -e '0,/version/s/.* = *//p' build.gradle
```

Comment: This is bad, because this will find and print all lines before the first match, if the first match is not at the first line